# Proving that two circles with one point in common have coincident tangent lines at that point

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, circles, tangent-line

Friends:

> Suppose that $\Gamma_{1}$ and $\Gamma_{2}$ are two circumferences that are externally tangent (they have exactly one point in common and neither of them is contained in the region bounded by the other one). Let us denote with $P$ the point of contact of these two circumferences. Prove that the tangent to $\Gamma_{1}$ that passes through $P$ coincides with the tangent to $\Gamma_{2}$ that passes through $P$.

How would a proof of this assertion from first principles go?

Thanks in advance for your suggestions.

Comment: How do you define that two circles are tangent? Isn't it just that they share the same tangent line?

Comment: Nope, that they intersect in exactly one point

Comment: @Jamai Could you provide a drawing of your claim - ONE POINT INTERSECTION? You have a perpendicular line at P to the segment connecting the two centers, for either circle (circumference?) - through a point on a line there is only one perpendicular.