# Proving that two circles intersecting at only one point share a common tangent line trough the given point

Tags: proof-writing, circles, tangent-line

#### In a textbook the following problem example:

> Two circles touch at point $M$. Through the point $M$ straight lines are drawn that intersect one circle at points $A_{1}$ and $B_{1}$, and the other at points $A_{2}$ and $B_{2}$. Prove that $A_{1}B_{1} \parallel A_{2}B_{2}$.

#### Has the next proof(its beginning):

> Let's draw a tangent CD to one of the circles through the point M. This line will also be tangent to the second circle **(prove this statement yourself)**...

#### The figure itself:

[image]

After some attempts of "proving this statement myself" I went searching for the solution, and the only similar question I've found was [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4125937/proving-that-two-circles-with-one-point-in-common-have-coincident-tangent-lines) with no answers.

###### How to prove that the line $CD$ is tangent to both of the circles at the point $M$, when it's tangent to one of them?

##### P.s. Note that it's only an 8th-grade-school problem, so a proof must be within the range of the 8th grade curriculum.

Answer (score 1):

You can show that $M$ is on the  segment which ends are centers of both circle, if you have that, the end result is direct :) You can say that there is only one perpendicular line passing through a specific point.

Let us denote $O_1,r_1$ respectively the center and radius of the first circle, and same with the second.
To show it we only need to show that $M = \frac{r_2}{r_1+r_2} O_1 + \frac{r_1}{r_1+r_2} O_2 $ or in affine geometry terms which should be more suitable for $8^{th}$ grade studs
$$\overrightarrow{O_1M} + \overrightarrow{MO_2} = \overrightarrow{O_1 O_2}.$$

We have $|O_i M| = r_i$.
From the triangle inequality we have
$$|O_1O_2| \leqslant r_1 + r_2.$$

We set $N = O_1 + \frac{r_1}{r_1 +r_2}\overrightarrow{O_1O_2}$,
$$|O_1N| = \frac{r_1}{r_1 +r_2}|O_1O_2| \leqslant r_1$$
so $N \in C(O_1,r_1)$.
We also have
$$|O_2 N| = (1- \frac{r_1}{r_1 +r_2})|O_1O_2| = \frac{r_2}{r_1 +r_2}|O_1O_2| \leqslant r_2$$
so $N \in C(O_2,r_2)$, hence $N$ lies in the intersection of the two disks, thus $N = M$, which proves the point :)

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer. What you're talking about is quite the same as what I need to prove. Of course, If the centers of the cricles and $M$ are collinear, then it would mean that $CD$ is perpendicular to both radii of the circles that meet at at the point $M$, hence $CD$ is tangent to both of the circles.

Comment: I'm sorry, I thought you wanted the steps of the proof, you want me to write everything down?

Comment: I edited it according to your remark :) I think this is now ok ?