# Proving that two tangent circles, in the case when one is insrcibed into the other, share common tangent line

Tags: geometry, proof-writing, circles, tangent-line

#### The problem:

> Given two circles with different radii, they intersect each other only at one point $M$. The smaller circle is inscribed into the bigger circle. **Prove that a tangent line to one circle is also tangent to the other cicle.**

#### The figure:

[image]

I could prove that if a tangent line is tangent to the bigger circle, then it's also tangent to the smaller one, but I'm confused with **the opposite case**. On the picture tangent line initially belongs to the circle with the center $O_{1}$.

I've tried to prove that $O_{1}O + O_{1}M = OM$, or that $O_{1}M$ is also perpendicular to the tangent line of the smaller circle by finding some contradiction, but none of that worked. **How to prove it?**

*Please, consider that it's only 8th grade curriculum and I need to prove it within the topic of: "Central and inscribed angles".*

Comment: If you briefly describe how you went about case starting from the bigger circle, we might be able to guide you on a similar proof starting from the smaller circle

Comment: Your picture assumes that we know that the two radii overlap.  That is to say, you assume that the relevant radius from the center of the big circle passes through the center of the small circle.  If you know that, you are done, since there is only one perpendicular to a given line through a given point.  But I wouldn't call that claim obvious.

Comment: This is a near duplicate of [your prior question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4720411/proving-that-two-circles-intersecting-at-only-one-point-share-a-common-tangent-l).  You should be able to adapt the arguments used in that case to this similar case.

Comment: @lulu yes, but the fact that they overlap on the picture doesn't prove the initial statement. I've made the figure with geogebra and so I simply can't draw the right figure where the $O, O_{1}, M$ are not collinear. About *my prior question*, yes, it's from the same problem, but the cases are different, and I unfortunately can't apply to this case what helped me to prove the prior case.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what's within the scope of your curriculum, but here's the outline for an argument based proof:

1. Consider the first circle, a point $M$ on it, and a line $L$ tangent at $M$.
2. The second circle shares only the point $M$ with the first circle.
3. Since line $L$ contains $M$, it must intersect the second circle at least at $M$.
4. If line $L$ is not tangent to the second circle, then it must intersect as a chord. So there is a second point $M'$ shared by the line and the second circle, and $MM'$ is the chord formed.
5. The second circle goes from $M$ to $M'$ on both sides of $MM'$. On one of these sides, it must enter the interior of the first circle.
6. $M'$ is outside the first circle, since it lies on line $L$ which touches the first circle only at $M$. So one of the arcs from $M$ to $M'$ would have to go from inside to outside the first circle, crossing it at some point $M^*$.
7. This implies $M^*$ is another point common to the two circles. But the problem statement says the two circles intersect at only one point.
8. This forces $M^* = M$, which is only possible when $M = M'$ as well.
9. Hence, the line $L$ cannot intersect the second circle at another point distinct from $M$. Therefore, it is tangent to the second circle.

Comment: Hi, Tony. Thanks for the answer! I don't really understand what you mean in 5th step by: "*The second circle goes from $M$ to $M′$ on both sides of $MM′$*". Could you explain, please ?

Comment: $M$ and $M'$ are two points on the second circle. So these two points are connected via an arc of the circle. In fact, they are connected by two arcs of the circle, formed by the chord $MM'$ splitting the circle. One arc goes around one side of $MM'$, the other arc goes around the other side

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't get it. How is this necessarily true: "$M$ and $M′$ are two points on the second circle. So these two points are connected via an arc of the circle."? How can they be connected by an arc of the first circle, if only 1 point is mutual for the bigger and smaller circles.

Comment: I should have clarified that I meant the two points are connected by an arc of the second circle.

Comment: Thank you for your time, Tony! But I unfortunately don't seem to catch the correctness of your proof. Why does the arc $MM′$ necessarily enter the interior of the first circle? I've been trying to google further more, but wherever it's mentioned about my case, it's used as a fact/property that doesn't need a proof, that the points $O, O_{1}, M$ are collinear. And I want to understand why and how it's provable.

Comment: Ah, that part is a bit more difficult to explain in words. It might be easier if you try drawing the situation: draw one circle, draw a tangent line to it at some point $M$, and choose another point $M'$ on the tangent line. Then try to draw a second circle which goes through $M$ and $M'$, but does not go through the interior of the first circle.